# Running a .jar on a Mac

Tags: mac, macos, java

I've recently been wishing I could still play a **Minigolf** game that came installed with my first cell phone, a [Sony Ericsson T610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_T610) (eat your heart out, iPhone!), which roughly looked like this:

[image]

<sup>*'Member?*</sup>

There are good reasons to believe that the game is "abandonware" and that Sony Ericsson doesn't offer support for it anymore.

I think the game can be found as a .jar file online, and is either [this one](http://www.mobiles24.co/downloads/s/448097-m356-real_minigolf_2005_128x160_se_t630) or [this one](http://www.mobiles24.co/downloads/s/448096-m356-real_minigolf_2005_128x160_se_k500i).

However, after downloading these files, I haven't been able to run them. **Java** is installed in the **/Library** folder of the **Macintosh HD** drive, and when I right-click the file to open it, I get a *"The Java JAR file “Real_Minigolf_2005_128x128_SE_K300i-448093.jar” could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages."* error message.

I have looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828076/how-to-run-a-jar-in-mac) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069825/how-to-run-jar-files-in-mac-using-jre?noredirect=1&lq=1), but neither have worked.

**Is it possible to run these files on a Mac running El Capitan or above?**

Answer (score 4):

In general, you run a ‘runnable JAR’ by opening it or with Terminal `java -jar /path/to/game.jar`.

However, this JAR does not contain a suitable manifest for launching, i.e. not a runnable JAR.

```
$ java -jar /path/to/game.jar  
no main manifest attribute, in /path/to/game.jar
```

Therefore you have to specify the main class manually. However, that still doesn't work.

```
$ java -cp /path/to/game.jar E
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics
[…]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics
[…]
```

That's because this JAR doesn't support being run on a computer. It's a game for a mobile device and you can't launch it on a computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any way to run it within another frame, like as a part of an emulated OS?