# When try to I open a .jar I get "The java JAR file could not be opened"

Tags: macos, java

[image: This is the popup I get please help]

***Found this error:Could not find or load main class E Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: E***

I am trying to install Forge so I can load mods for Minecraft.

Comment: also when I run it on the console it pops up as :

MacBook-Air:~ max$ java -jar ~/Dowloads/forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1722-universal-2.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile /Users/max/Dowloads/forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.1722-universal-2.jar

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283882/running-a-jar-on-a-mac

Comment: What is the output of `jar -tf [PATH_TO_JAR_FILE]`?

Comment: abc it says **-bash: xjar: command not found**

Comment: @AspectGamez does the other question I linked answer your query ? Also, using just the username didnt notify abc. Please use @ to do that. One person per comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Those jar files are not executed by double-clicking. You have to place it in .minecraft/versions folder and run it from launcher I think.

Comment: Thanks tried that didn't work still.